# Как парсить html таблицу в Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

У меня есть таблица

[image]

с таким html кодом

```
<table class="grid">
<colgroup span="1" />
<colgroup width="7.1%" span="12" />
<tr><th>Year</th><th colspan="12">Month</th></tr>

<tr>
<td>2011</td>
<td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td>
<td><a href="https://www.gokgs.com/gameArchives.jsp?user=asdkk&amp;oldAccounts=t&amp;year=2011&amp;month=9">Sep</a></td>
<td><a href="https://www.gokgs.com/gameArchives.jsp?user=asdkk&amp;oldAccounts=t&amp;year=2011&amp;month=10">Oct</a></td>
<td><a href="https://www.gokgs.com/gameArchives.jsp?user=asdkk&amp;oldAccounts=t&amp;year=2011&amp;month=11">Nov</a></td>
<td><a href="https://www.gokgs.com/gameArchives.jsp?user=asdkk&amp;oldAccounts=t&amp;year=2011&amp;month=12">Dec</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2012</td>
<td><a href="https://www.gokgs.com/gameArchives.jsp?user=asdkk&amp;oldAccounts=t&amp;year=2012&amp;month=1">Jan</a></td>
<td><a href="https://www.gokgs.com/gameArchives.jsp?user=asdkk&amp;oldAccounts=t&amp;year=2012&amp;month=2">Feb</a></td>
<td><a href="https://www.gokgs.com/gameArchives.jsp?user=asdkk&amp;oldAccounts=t&amp;year=2012&amp;month=3">Mar</a></td>
<td><a href="https://www.gokgs.com/gameArchives.jsp?user=asdkk&amp;oldAccounts=t&amp;year=2012&amp;month=4">Apr</a></td>
<td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Я пытаюсь распарсить таблицу и вот мой код

**xml**

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="13">
</GridView>
```

**Jsoup lib**

```
    try {
        Document verb = Jsoup.connect("https://www.gokgs.com/gameArchives.jsp?user=" + nickname + "&oldAccounts=y").get();
        Element tableVerb = verb.select("p ~ table.grid").first();
        Elements rowsVerb = tableVerb.select("tr");

        titleList.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < rowsVerb.size(); i++) {
            Element row = rowsVerb.get(i);
            Elements cols = row.select("td");
                for (Element e: cols){
                   if (e.hasAttr("colspan")) {
                       int colspan = Integer.valueOf(cols.attr("colspan"));
                       for (int y = 0; y < colspan; y++){
                           titleList.add(y, e.text().toString());
                       }
                   } else {
                       titleList.add(e.text().toString());
                   }
                }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

В результате получаю следующую таблицу

[image]

Моя таблица имеет 13 колонок(год+ 12 мес.). Если отсутствуют некоторые месяцы в таблице, то в html коде используется тег `<td colspan = "число">&nbsp;</ td>`.

У меня добавляются сперва все пустые ячейки, а необходимо повторить таблицу с сайта. Где ошибка?

Comment: `Integer.valueOf(cols.attr("colspan"));` -> `Integer.valueOf(e.attr("colspan"));` `titleList.add(y, e.text().toString());` -> `titleList.add(e.text().toString());`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!